# aws のインスタンスの ssh の config を効率よく編集(追加)するパッケージはありますか？

Tags: aws, emacs, ssh

aws インスタンスに対して、以下の条件を満たす ssh config 用の elisp パッケージはありますか？

1. 接続の `Host`, `HostName` をクエリする
2. `User` などには、何も入力されなければデフォルト値 (設定可能)  を用いる
3. 複数鍵のパスを設定で管理でき、その中から今回設定するものを指定できる
4. その結果が .ssh/config に append される
5. (その他便利機能。)

背景:

aws 上でいくつものサーバーを管理する際に、 tramp で接続するための設定を効率化したいため。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

なかった様子なので、自作を始めました。上に挙げた要件は実装できている状態です。

- https://github.com/Yuki-Inoue/aws.el

Answer (score 0):

期待する条件にはほど遠いですが、
基本的なキーワードの色付け機能を備えた`ssh-config-mode.el`というパッケージはあります。

https://github.com/jhgorrell/ssh-config-mode-el

Answer (score 0):

[ec2ssh](https://github.com/mirakui/ec2ssh) が、自分の欲しかったものなのではないか、と思いはじめています。 ec2 への sshconfig を、自動で生成してくれるツールの様子です。